# accessing inverse hasmany in controller laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables `topics`, `category`(HowtoCategory::class), `sections`(Howto::class).

Multiple categories belong to one topic and multiple sections belong to one category.

- `Topic` Has Many `Category`
- `Category` Has Many `Sections`
- `Category` Belongs to `Topic`
- `Sections` Belongs To `Category`
- `Topic` Has Many `Sections` Through `Category`

I want to search through the `sections`(Howto::class) but display the related `topics`. How can I access `topics` in the controller from my query search of `sections`? I dont want to access it in the view but in the controller.

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if (request()->filled('search')) {
            request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['search ' => null]);
            $sections = Howto::search($request->search)->get();
            $request = $request->input('search');
        } else {
            $sections = null;
        }

        return view('howto-pages.howto-main', [
            'sections' => $sections,
        ]);
    }
```

**Models**

```
class Topic extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(HowtoCategory::class);
    }

    public function sections()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Howto::class, HowtoCategory::class);
    }
}

class HowtoCategory extends Model
{
    public function sections()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Howto::class);
    }

    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class);
    }
}

class Howto extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(HowtoCategory::class);
    }
}
```

**Tables**

```
mysql> desc howto;
+-------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title             | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body              | mediumtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description       | mediumtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| section_id        | int             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| howto_category_id | bigint unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc howto_category;
+----------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| howto_category_title | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| icon                 | varchar(255)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description          | mediumtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| intro                | text            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id          | int             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at           | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at           | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| topic_id             | bigint unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc topics;
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| topic_title | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | mediumtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Why did you add the same question again?

Comment: @GertB. if this is a duplicate then please flag it as such

Comment: @SuperDJ, i did

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost i'd define the **foreignIDS** in the relations just to make sure that are working as expected.

```
class Topic extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(HowtoCategory::class);
    }

    public function sections()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Howto::class, HowtoCategory::class,
           "topic_id", "howto_category_id"
        );
    }
}
```

then you can get the Topics by searching the sections like so

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$topics = Topic::whereHas("sections", function(Builder $query) {
    $query->where("howto.description", "something to search")
})->get();
```